# Using ng-model with new elements added to the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some angular code that adds a some input textboxes to a div. I want to add ng-module="..." to those newly created textboxes but it seems if I do that they do not get registered as models by angular.

Basically I'm trying to create these input boxes at runtime, give them a ng-model attribute and then create a div which includes the model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="placeholder_name" />
....
<div id="content">{{placeholder_name}}</div>
```

app.js

```
var ViewCtrl = function($scope, $location, $routeParams, Template) {
    var id = $routeParams.templateId;
    var template = Template.get({id: id}, function(res) {
        $scope.template = template;
    });

    /*** Template placeholders ***/
    $scope.updatePlaceholders = function () {
        var placeholders = [];
        var content = template.content;

        // get placeholders that match patter
        var match = content.match(/{([A-z0-9]+)}/gmi);

        // if there are placeholders
        if (match !== null) {
            // foreach placeholder
            for (var i = match.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                // strip braces
                var holder = match[i].replace(/(}|{)/g, '');
                // add to placeholders array
                placeholders.push(holder);
            }
        }

        // remove duplicates
        $scope.placeholders = $.unique(placeholders);

        // now go through each placeholder in content box and replace with {{model}}.
        for (var k = 0; k < placeholders.length; k++) {
            var placeholder_new = '<span class="placeholder placeholder-' + placeholders[k] + '">{{' + placeholders[k] + '}}</span>';
            var regex = new RegExp("{" + placeholders[k] + "}", "g");
            var new_content = $scope.template.content.replace(regex, placeholder_new);
            $scope.template.content = new_content;
        }
    }
}
```

view.html

```
<h2>Template: {{template.title}}</h2>
<div class="well well-small">
    <p><strong>Placeholders</strong></p>
    <div class="placeholder-list">
        <span ng-repeat="placeholder in placeholders">  
            <input type="text" class="span2 placeholder" ng-model="placeholder_{{placeholder}}" value="{{placeholder}}" />
            <span ng-show=" ! $last ">&nbsp;</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div contenteditable="true" id="content" ng-bind-html="template.content"></div>
```

The idea is that my template.content contains text like this:

```
Look! {this} is a placeholder.
```

I find all the instances of {...} and create input boxes for them. I then replace {...} with `<span>{{<model>}}</span>` with the idea being when I change the value of the tet box then this spans content changes

This line is throwing an error. Doesn't like the way I am creating the ng-model:

```
<input type="text" class="span2 placeholder" ng-model="placeholder_{{placeholder}}" value="{{placeholder}}" />
```

> Error: Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 13 of
>   the expression [placeholder_{{placeholder}}] starting at
>   [{{placeholder}}].

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `ng-repeat`? Constructing html content like this, is really not the *angular-way*.

Comment: I'm porting my js from jQuery, still not aware of all the angular features. I'll be taking your advice though!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you'd post your model-data, or whatever data would trigger the placement/changes to the template and maybe an excerpt of the wanted target result. Also some explanation whether you're working with a directive or a general controller.

Comment: rule of thumb in angular: don't do DOM stuff in javascript code (except in directives but you'll get to that later)

Comment: I think I know where you want to go with that. Though I would structure it differently. I'll try to add an answer later.